# Angular 2 input parameters on root directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

[This](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html) example shows how to use @Input() annotation on child components. My question is how do you use it on root component? For example if you modify code on the link above:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app',
template: `
    <bank-account bank-name="RBC" account-id="4747"></bank-account>
`,
directives: [BankAccount]
})
class App {
    @Input() something: string;
}

bootstrap(App);
```

And in html:

```
<app something="Test"></app>
```

The above example never updates *something* property on App component.

Comment: I have been wanting to do this as well. Added a bug a while back https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4921

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This Tobias Bosch's comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-151326461) has answer on your question:

> The reason why this is not working is that your index.html in which you place the `<app something="Test"></app>` is not an angular component. Because of this, Angular won't compile this element. And Angular does not read attribute values during runtime, only during compile time, as otherwise we would get a performance hit.

So, at this moment you can't use input parameters on root element.

Comment: how to pass array of objects from express/jade to an angular2 component? I wanted to bind that way and it doesn't work.

Comment: If it has the @Component decorator, how is it not an angular component?

Answer (score 23):

I think you could still use:

```
class App {
    constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
        this.something = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('something'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. ElementRef can be imported from angular2//core.

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) Works perfect with static values!

Comment: [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) is marked with SECURITY RISK label, so be careful using it.

Comment: This will not work if you are using angular universal to render on the server for SEO.