# Angular 2. Pass parameter to a component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I would like to pass a string parameter to my component. Depending on passing parameter i will pass different parameters for services in my component. I do next: In index.html call my component, passing parameter.

```html
<top [mode]="tree">Loading...</top>
```

In my component i include Input from angular2/core

```js
import {Input, Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
```

In my component`s class i declare an input

```js
@Input() mode: string;
```

And with console.log() i try to catch my passing parameter of 'tree', but it`s undefined.

```js
console.log(this, this.mode);
```

[image]

The full code of a component file:

```js
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {Input, Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ParticipantService} from '../services/participant.service';
import {orderBy} from '../pipes/orderby.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'top',
    templateUrl: 'dev/templates/top.html',
    pipes: [orderBy],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ParticipantService]
})
export class AppTopComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor (private _participantService: ParticipantService) {}

    errorMessage: string;
    participants: any[];
    @Input() mode: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this, this.mode);
        this.getParticipants('top3');
        var self = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            self.getParticipants('top3');
        }, 3000);
    }

    getParticipants(public mode: string) {
        this._participantService.getParticipants(mode)
            .then(
                participants => this.participants = participants,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't do these things in your root component. Its purpose is just to hold the app, not to be used as a component itself. Start from the first child component and you'll avoid all those ugly workarounds.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `[...]`, the value you provide corresponds to an expression that can be evaluated.

So `tree` must be something that exists in the parent component and correspond to a string.

If you want to use the string `tree`, use this:

```
<top mode="tree">Loading...</top>
```

You can notice that **such parameters can't be used for root component**. See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 input parameters on root directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640178/angular-2-input-parameters-on-root-directive/33641842#33641842)

Comment: Don't you want to use: [mode]="treee"

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround for the limitation Thierry explained you can use

```
constructor(private _participantService: ParticipantService, 
    elRef:ElementRef) {
  this.mode=elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('mode');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait until template is bound to DOM. in order to do this, you have to implement AfterViewInit

```
    export class AppTopComponent implements AfterViewInit{

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this, this.mode);
        this.getParticipants('top3');
        var self = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            self.getParticipants('top3');
        }, 3000);
    }
   }
```