# Angular2, TypeScript, How to read/bind attribute value to component class (undefined in ngOnInit)

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

can someone please advice me how to read/bind attribute value to @component class, which seems to be undefined in ngOnInit method?

Here's a plunker demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4FoFNBFsOEvvOkyfn0lw?p=preview

I'd like to read value of "someattribute" attribute

```
<my-app [someattribute]="'somevalue'">
```

inside the App class (src/app.ts) ngOninit method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can notice that **such parameters can't be used for root component**. See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 input parameters on root directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640178/angular-2-input-parameters-on-root-directive/33641842#33641842)

The workaround consists in leveraging the `ElementRef` class. It needs to be injected into your main component:

```
constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
  this.someattribute = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('someattribute'); 
}
```

We need to use the component this way in the HTML file:

```
<my-app someattribute="somevalue"></my-app>
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. This doesn't work as well. Please see the plunker.

Comment: No worries! I updated my answer... The problem is because you try to use this on the main component of your application (the one you use to bootstrap it)

Comment: Yes! That's it... I did not realized that I cannot use attributes in a root component. Can you please remove 'interpolation' part of your answer and keep just part below 'code'? Just to avoid confusion of users like me.

Comment: This is a bad idea because of the security ricks and coupling to the DOM as noted in the API.

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html

use the @Input decorator

Comment: The security risks pertain to DOM manipulation. If you read further into the security guide (https://angular.io/guide/security#direct-use-of-the-dom-apis-and-explicit-sanitization-calls) it's the ElementRef's `document` node that has unsafe methods. Simply reading attributes from a DOM element is not an inherit security risk.

You can also use a third-party library like StencilJS which supports creating custom properties on components: https://stenciljs.com/docs/properties

Answer (score 18):

You should use `@Input` decorator.

This is an example:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-menu',
    templateUrl: 'user-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['user-menu.component.scss'],
})
export class UserMenuComponent {

    /**
     * userName Current username
     */
    @Input('userName') userName: string;

    constructor() {

    }
    sayMyName() {
        console.log('My name is', this.userName);
    }
}
```

And to use it

```
<user-menu userName="John Doe"></user-menu>
```

Comment: this is a much better approach than reading the getAttribute if not used on the root element

Comment: This must be accepted answer. A proper way to get attribute.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue with creating a custom attribute on a root component. While this solution is file for a parent/child component property binding, the accepted answer is correct for what the scenario (root component).

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

Inputs aren't supported in the root component as a workaround you can use

```
constructor(elementRef:ElementRef) {
  console.log(elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('someattribute');
}
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858

See also the fixed [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YCldRmtxB9zobmeOmRv2?p=preview)

**original**

You need to either use

```
[property]="value"
```

or

```
property="{{value}}"
```

or if it's an attribute

```
[attr.property]="value"
```

or

```
attr.property="{{value}}"
```