# understanding ngOnChanges lifecyle hook

Tags: angular

Below is the explanination provided for OnChanges life cycle event in
angular2 documentation.

***ngOnChanges - before ngOnInit and when a data-bound input property value 
changes.***

Below is my sample component code

```js
@Component({
   selector:'app-main',
   template:`
      <user-form>Loading....</user-form>
   `,
   directives: [userFormComponent],
   providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS,UserService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit , OnChanges {

  @Input()
  public prop: string = "hi!";

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log('ngOnInt') ;
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
     console.log('ngOnChanges') ;
  }  

}
```

And I am refering to this component in my html page like this

```html
<app-main [prop]="test">Loading...</app-main>
```

Now my question is, even though I am changing databound input property "prop" by
 assiging value "test", why is that ngOnChanges is not executed. By the way I am new to angular2.

Comment: I believe that only happens on the main component (`AppComponent`). It should work the way it was described on inner components. May due to boostrap process.

Comment: That sounds like it.  In your example, where should `test` come from?  Normally that would be a property on the parent component, but since it's your root app component, there's no component for your index html with a 'test' property to pass to `[prop]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this doesn't apply to main components / root components.

> The reason why this is not working is that your index.html in which you place the  is not an angular component. Because of this, Angular won't compile this element. And Angular does not read attribute values during runtime, only during compile time, as otherwise, we would get a performance hit.

For this reason, the `ngOnChanges` hook method doesn't apply.

See this question:

- [Angular2, TypeScript, How to read/bind attribute value to component class (undefined in ngOnInit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628053/angular2-typescript-how-to-read-bind-attribute-value-to-component-class-undef/35628064#35628064)

Comment: Hi, can you suggest some link where I can find more info on lifecycle hooks, because the information provided in angular2 docs is not in detail.

Comment: Did you read the following doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html?