# How to pass variable outside angular application into outer html?

Tags: angular

I have static header and footer outside my angular app, and i need to show some variable there.

```
<some-html>variable</some-html>
<app-root></app-root>
```

That string i am getting from the cookie service inside my angular app. Actually i know that i can write some logic outside angular app and get this data separately.

But i wonder are that any other possible way to pass this data to outer markup, that are outside `app-root`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use variables outside the application you can use sessionStorage, sessionStorage is bound to the browser tab. If want it in multiple tabs use localStorage.

Example:

`sessionStorage.setItem('variable', JSON.stringify(variable));`

To get the variable can use:

`JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('variable'));`

Answer (score 0):

Property binding doesn't work on the root components, i.e. the components you bootstrap.

> The reason why this is not working is that your index.html in which
>   you place the
>
> is not an angular component. Because of this, Angular won't compile
>    this element. And Angular does not read attribute values during
>    runtime, only during compile time, as otherwise, we would get a
>    performance hit. (Tobias Bosch)

**Quoting @Thierry Templier** **from** [Pass data from html body to root component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843104/pass-data-from-html-body-to-root-component)

> A workaround would be to leverage the DOM:
>
> `<my-app bodyData="passed" ></my-app>`
>    and in the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    (...)
  `
})
export class MyAppComponent {
  constructor(private eltRef:ElementRef) {
    let prop = eltRef.getAttribute('bodyData');
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want any property binding, i just want this variable to be on window.myVarable accesible. All i wrote it is just scheme to show that i want to achieve.

Comment: I must've misunderstood. You want to pass data from inside Angular to the index.html file that wraps the <root>?