# is there any way to pass data from component to index.html page in angular 5

Tags: angular5

[from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843104/pass-data-from-html-body-to-root-component) I got a solution for passing data from index.html to component,but is there any way to pass data vice-versa(component to index.html) in angular 5?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question to me, what do you need to achieve?

Comment: is it possible to pass data to index.html  in angular?

Comment: What data are you trying to pass into index.html? Sounds like you have a design issue more than an angular issue

Comment: can i pass dynamic data of type object into index.html