# How to read object created on Index.html <script> tag in the constructor of Angular Service

Tags: angular

In Angular Universal or Angular Server Side Rendered Application. I am using CDN of MSAL.js, as its module does not support server-side rendering.

Now, I have a service with provideIn set to 'root'. In this service constructor, I am trying to read an object created on Index.HTML file.

So in Index.html , I have

var abc = {
      name:'dj'
    }

I want to read this value in constructor of a service. How to do that any  help ?

Comment: Does this answer your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843104/pass-data-from-html-body-to-root-component ?

Comment: No, it does not as my question specifically says I am looking to read the value in Angular Universal app, not in normal Angular app