# Using @Input decorator to pass data from outside the angular component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In an ionic app, i am using a angular component. In that angular component, i have a variable `headerText` which in initialized from the page where this component is used.

Problem is that `headerText` variable is always undefined.

How can i fix this problem?

This is the angular component where `headerText` variable is defined.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-header-text',
  templateUrl: 'custom-header-text.html'
})
export class CustomHeaderTextComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() headerText: string;

  constructor(private navCtrl :  NavController,
              private menuCtrl : MenuController) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('text = ' + this.headerText);
    }, 3000);
  }

  goBack() {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }

  openMenuPage() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true,'bl-menu')
    this.menuCtrl.open();
  }
}
```

This is how i am passing a value to this `headerText` variable from where this component is used.

```
<custom-header-text [headerText]="'Inbox'"></custom-header-text>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: no, there are no errors

Comment: Can you replicate this issue with a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic)?

Comment: Are you calling the custom-header-text selector in index.html or your root element?

Comment: @Marshal i am using custom-header-text selector in an ionic page.

Comment: Is the ionic page the root element? meaning is the first thing called by the browser in your project? Sorry I am not familiar with ionic

Comment: @SiddAjmera i have posted my relevant code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3mhutq?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) but i couldn't fix couple of broken imports but hopefully you will get an idea of what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: @Marshal Yes it is the root page. But after setting another page as root page and then opening this page from there, problem was solved. Any idea why root page was the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below.

> The reason why this is not working is that your root element in which
>   you place the `<custom-header-text [headerText]="'Inbox'"></custom-header-text>` is not an angular
>   component. Because of this, Angular won't compile this element. And
>   Angular does not read attribute values during runtime, only during
>   compile time, as otherwise we would get a performance hit.

Answered here

[Angular 2 input parameters on root directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640178/angular-2-input-parameters-on-root-directive)

Comment: So that means i cannot pass data to the angular component in this way from the root element in ionic?

Comment: There is an example in the linked answer that shows how to get string values, you could possibly use that here as you want a string let prop = eltRef.getAttribute('headerText'); but anything beyond a string value I believe you will not be able to. I ran into this in my project doing a browser check, I will keep looking to see if there is a way for data beyond a string but getAttribute should work  for your string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wasn't working as the HeaderModule was not correctly configured.

There were a few issues with your implementation:

1. The path to the Header Module wasn't correctly set in AppModule.
2. The path to the HeaderComponent template was also not set to the correct HTML file.

After fixing those, it was working as expected. Here's an [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dcppfn?file=Components/header.ts) for your ref.

Comment: yes, i couldn't set the correct paths to files on Stackblitz but in my project on my pc, paths are correctly configured, setting another page as root page fixed this issue.